# How do I remove the .html extension from the output of cmsfn.link?

Tags: freemarker, magnolia

The [`cmsfn.link`](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/cmsfn#cmsfn-Createlinktoanode) templating function includes an `.html` extension in its output.

For example:

```
${cmsfn.link(exampleNode)}
```

Outputs:

```
https://examplesite.com/example-page.html
```

How do I remove the `.html` extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be done via Magnolia configuration and Magnolia ["won't be able to address this issue in the foreseeable future"](https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MAGNOLIA-3925). But there are three FreeMarker built-in options:

### Option 1: [replace](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_replace)

```
${cmsfn.link(exampleNode)?replace(".html", "")}
```

### Option 2: [split](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_split)

```
${cmsfn.link(exampleNode)?split(".html")[0]}
```

### Option 3: [remove_ending](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_remove_ending)

```
${cmsfn.link(exampleNode)?remove_ending(".html")}
```